# Sql server Not listed in PlasticScm Server configuration wizard

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2016, plasticscm

I want to use MS Sql Server as my Database backend with PlasticScm.

When I click to configure it , my Database is not listed in backend server.
It just show embedded backend.

I have also checked Sql server is running

I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 and Sql server 2016.

Comment: Is SQL Browser running ? What port is the instance configured on ? Is it a named SQL instance ? Are the ports opened (default is 1433, browser port is 1434) ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Hybris but ... No , SQL Server Browser wasn't running , I made it start , The firewall is turned off , But PlasticScm still doesn't list SQL server.

Comment: What about named instance and port ? Is it on a dynamic range or is it a fixed port (default one) ? You can check this on Configuration Manager

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server, Oracle and PostgreSQL are only supported if you are using an Enterprise edition license. If you aren't, those options won't be even listed in the server configurator:
https://www.plasticscm.com/pricing.html

Comment: Please could you contact us to support at codicesoftware dot com ?